# Is Yaoi and Yuri on-topic on A&M.SE?

Tags: discussion, support

What is the criteria for this and are we allowed to ask questions on animes shows that are usually Yaoi or Yuri related in nature? Please do not get this confused with Hentai!

An answer would be nice. I would like to know since it seems that hentai related questions seem to be allowed. Not sure why though?

Answers are appreciated.

Note: I am asking this question because I was planning on asking questions related to a Yaoi such as Jonjou Romantica. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: Should point out, in Japan, the terms Yuri/Yaoi include all works of those themes including hentai, it is in the west that the terms particularly relate to henati. if you happen to be in the west and you want to mention Yuri/Yaoi but make sure no one confuses it for Hentai you can use the terms Shoujo Ai (Yuri) and Shounen Ai (Yaoi). that being said, anyone who is really invested in Yuri/Yaoi who can give you good quality answers will know that when you say Yuri/Yaoi you not talking about only hentai

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definetly, I've asked questions about Yuri items before and I don't see why Yaoi would be any different:

[Why did the Strawberry Panic manga end?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4447/why-did-the-strawberry-panic-manga-end)

If it's something explicit in nature, be sure to try and make the content sfw as @Braiam has mentioned, but as a genre they are perfectly fine

Answer (score 3):

As long as it's anime/manga related independently the genre are on topic and can be asked in Anime.SE. We would kindly ask that you should be make your posts Safe For Work (SFW).

So, for your specific concern, Yaoi and Yuri genres are on topic as long as you express yourself with professionalism fit of the SE site.